# Access query with criteria to prompt user

Tags: ms-access

I have created a small database for Bill of Lading, I have a Form created from query, where user will enter the product code, the product description, and case weight will populate.

There are some product does not have the specific weights and I am using 0 in the product table. is there any way I can use a criteria in the query, when user enter the product code in the form which has 0 value its prompt user to enter the case weight, otherwise use the weight in the table.

Please see below for screen shots.
    [image: Form]
    [image: Query]
    [image: Table]

Comment: Elaborate your question. Add screenshot of the tables and query. This will get you more answers.

Comment: thanks Adarsh, posted some screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you properly, you want to prompt users to enter `weight` if `weight` in the table is `0`. 
This can be achieved through writing some VBA Code. I would suggest, this code `onChange` event of the `Product Code` text box.

The pseudocode will be as below:

```
If DLookup("CaseWeight" , "tblProduct" , "Code = me.txtbox.value") = 0 then
  //Prompt Users to enter data
else
  //Continue query execution.
end if
```

Comment: Thanks again Adarsh, my VBA Skills is very low, will you please add some more detail code.

Comment: @Abbas, It will be difficult to tell you the exact code unless you share what you have tried. I suggest, you first try to learn VBA. There are many great videos pn YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySyMn3H4rvg&list=PLhKFRV3-UgpeA_3wzRHF8AS8T7ppKvm9O

Comment: Another great option for learning - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kogGwRIHH6o&list=PLYMOUCVo86jEeMMdaaq03jQ_t9nFV737s